# Visual Studio 2022, Maui, Android Emulator: unable to change amount of memory

Tags: android, exception, android-emulator, maui, visual-studio-2022

*Visual Studio 2022, Maui 7.0, Android Emulator 32.1.1* (everything is the latest, up to date)

Working on a Maui App, and just got to the point where I need the app to play videos, so I installed the **CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement**.

### What's the problem?

It ran about twice until I started getting this exception, regardless of what virtual Android device was used:

> Error: ADB0060: Mono.AndroidTools.InsufficientSpaceException: There is not enough storage space on the device to store package: /data/local/tmp/com.aaavisiologix.ems_mobile_maui-Signed.apk. Free up some space and try again.

The Googling only leads me to how to free up space using Android Studio, not using Visual Studio.  There is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=windows&pivots=windows) Microsoft site, but if there's something on there about how to solve my problem, I couldn't understand it.

### What did I try?

I open the *Android Device Manager* in Visual Studio (Tools -> Android -> Android Device Manager), and it's apparent that my devices don't have a lot of memory:

[image]

So maybe I can make that a larger number?  Except I don't know how. Nothing in the "edit specific device" options were very helpful, except for the very first option: ***disk,dataPartition.size***, of which I tried every value one can think of.  This didn't change the amount of memory (still 1 GB) or the behavior of the device (still got exception).

[image]

I always make sure that I keep my test programs uninstalled on the machine, so... shouldn't that take care of any data I'm storing using *SecureStorage* or SQLite?

In the Microsoft doc it says to select the "Reveal In Explorer" option when you right-click on a device in Android Device Manager.  Alas, when I do that I get this error:

> C:\Users...\avd\devicename.avd is unavailable.  IF the location is on this PC, make sure the device or drive is connected or the disc is inserted...

How can I continue forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the **1GB** in the first image is the value of the **hw.ramsize** not the **disk,dataPartition.size**. It's the RAM memory.

In addition, I have checked the default value of the **disk,dataPartition.size** in my android emulator. It's **6442450944 bytes(6 GB)**. If you set it as 4G, you are reducing the memory.

So you can try to set a bigger value such as 8GB, 12GB or a bigger one for the **disk,dataPartition.size**.

Comment: Yeah, I did that (messed with the `disc.dataPartition.size` value).  I explain that in my orig post ("plus every value you can think of"), but I don't blame you for missing it.

Comment: Did you try to test on the phyxical device or create a new emulator with a default bigger `disc.dataPartition.size`? @Bob

Comment: In addition, did you try to restart the visual studio or the emulator and clean and rebuild the project after you edit the memory? @Bob

Comment: All of those things, yes, except for one problem... human error.

Comment: Changing the `disc.dataPartition.size` was the first thing I did.  I must not have saved it properly or something, because I did id again after your answer, and... it seems to be working.  (But I _swear_ I changed it correctly!  That's what everyone says.)  So if it works for a few more times, I'm certainly giving you the greeen checkmark.

Comment: Clean and rebuild or restart will resolve some strange problems sometimes. @Bob

Comment: I may be running into issues because I'm using embedded MP4 files.  My "source" isn't a URL, it's a file that I'm saving into `Resources\Raw`.  We'll see if the problem happens when I try adding a few MP4 files (the nature of the project doens't allow for URLs at this moment).

Comment: Yeah, maybe cleaning and restarting did the trick.

Comment: What's the value of your `disc.dataPartition.size` now? @Bob

Comment: I put it at 12G.  It's working fine.

Comment: Well, it's actually not working fine, but the exception isn't getting thrown, so that seems to have done the trick for that problem.  Thank you sir!  I probably wouldn't've taken a second look at that had you not said something.

Comment: Actually, the large file will take a big size for the device. So it's usually loaded from the web not the embedded source.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to see that.  However, these MP4s are 15 minute max, and although that's pretty big, it seems to work.  Eventually I'll have to use APIs to get these videos (actually not APIs but some super-complicated method that is scaring the heck out of me), but for now I can cheat and just load up 6 or 7 videos.